# Nhibernate, how to make unique string column

Tags: string, nhibernate, unique

I have example 'object' with Id, FkAnotherObject, and string. Which attribute I have to use to have ony unique strings in table. Is there any option to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`unique="true"` should do the trick :-)

Alternatively, `unique-key` allows you to create multi-column unique constraints.